How to combine enumerations with flags? tasks with flags in C#
everyone. I am a beginner in C# and recently I have faced one task, the logic for which is difficult for me to find. It sounds like this: Create an enumeration with flags(!), which stores the names of 6 software products - 3 systems for accounting automation and 3 systems for logistics management. Display the list of systems using constants (number - name). Allow the user to enter the numbers of the software products he would like to purchase in the form of a list, separating the numbers with commas. Print the name of the program author, lists of software products separately for each group (accounting/logistics).
The task itself is very easy, I wrote it quickly before. However, the task is to use flags, and this is where I got stuck. I would be very grateful for your help!
Here's how the code looked like before enter image description here( I'd be happy to receive criticism of this code as well). But I need to do something like this code(it's example):
{
    class Program
    {
        [Flags]
        enum Products
        {
            Not = 0b00000000,
            Butter = 0b00000001,
            Yogurt = 0b00000010,
            Orange = 0b00000100,
            Plum = 0b00001000,
            Sausage = 0b00010000,
            Ham = 0b00100000,
            Milk = 0b00000011,
            Fruit = Orange | Plum, 
            Meat = 0b00110000
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int goods;
            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Select product: ");
                Console.WriteLine("1. Butter ");
                Console.WriteLine("2. Yogurt ");
                Console.WriteLine("3. Orange ");
                Console.WriteLine("4. Plum ");
                Console.WriteLine("5. Sausage ");
                Console.WriteLine("6. Ham ");
                string text = Console.ReadLine();
                goods = Convert.ToInt16(text);
                if (goods >= 1 && goods <= 6) { break; }
            }
            int product = (int)Math.Pow(2, goods - 1);
            Console.WriteLine("Product selected: " + (Products)product);
            Console.WriteLine("This product belongs to the group: ");
            if (((Products)product & Products.Milk) != 0) //кон’юнкція
            {
                Console.Write(Products.Milk);
            }
            else
            {
                if (((Products)product & Products.Fruit) != 0)
                {
                    Console.Write(Products.Fruit);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.Write(Products.Meat);
                }
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

}

